# Prevent touch of previous screen in react native

Tags: android, react-native, stack-navigator

I am working in ReactNative project where I am using StackNavigator.

I am navigating from one functional component to another using navigation.

On the next screen I am able to touch the previous stack screen touchables i.e. button etc.

How to prevent the same?

**Note:** The issue seems to be in Android only.

Comment: can you please share an expo snack? it seems strange something like this will happen

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `navigation.push` instead of `navigation.navigate` to unmount previous screen.

Answer (score 0):

use **pointerEvents='none'** property in View